# CSS: How to set image width larger than the container's

Tags: html, css, image, resize, position

My task is simple, yet I cannot seem to complete it.

I have a `div` container with size of say 100px by 100px. It's position is set to `relative`, inside I have an image with position set to `absolute 0 0`. I want to set the size of the image to be 200px by 200px with CSS. What is cut out of the div will easily be hidden by setting `overflow: hidden`.

The problem here is that neither Chrome nor Mozilla will let me set an image size larger than the container's.

If it matters, the container lives inside another one with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Please provide the code you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Works fine for me (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/zdDBC/1/)

```
#wrapper
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: True, the problem seems to be in Twitter Bootstrap, now to find it..

Comment: There is `max-width` set to 100% in twitter bootstrap.. Now I feel stupid. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You never told us there was other CSS going on!!!

Comment: 3 kittens died because of that

Comment: Set max-height and max-width to none in the img.